# django base.html with htmx

Tags: django, django-templates, htmx

So question is i got my base.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- styles -->

</head>
<body>
    {% include 'includes/sidebar.html' %}
        <div id="main">
        {% block content %}


        {% endblock content %}
        </div>
    
    {% block js %}
    <!-- block where js is located -->
    {% endblock js%}

</body>
```

dashboard.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<!--my content-->
{% endblock content %}
```

and my sidebar.html

```html
% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<div id="sidebar" class="active">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper active">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

                <div class="toggler">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-hide d-xl-none d-block"><i class="bi bi-x bi-middle"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                 <li class="sidebar-item  has-sub">
                    <a href="#" class='sidebar-link'>
                        <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
                        <span>Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li class="submenu-item ">
                            {% url "dashboard:dashboard" as dashboard %}
                            <a href="{{ dashboard }}" 
                                hx-get="{{ dashboard}}" 
                                hx-target="#main" 
                                hx-push-url="true"
                                hx-indicator = "#content-loader"
                                hx-on="htmx:beforeRequest: event.detail.target.innerHTML = ''" 
                                class='submenu-link'>
                                <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
                                <span>{% trans 'Dashboard' %}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                    <!-- else code -->
```

So question is when user redirect from login page to dashboard, if im not extends from base.html it not shown any sidebar and its logical, but with htmlx when im extends base.html template this render me a template where two sidebars

Comment: You have to limit the html response to only the #main div, it's done either by `hx-select` or limiting the template response on the backend to only fetch the content of #main.